# How to mount the internal storage of the Droid 3?

Tags: usb, internal-storage, mount, motorola-droid-3

My father just got a Droid 3, and it has something like 12 or 16 gigs of internal storage. I'm trying to mount that storage to his laptop so he can transfer over music, but I'm not getting the USB Mount prompt that I've come to expect with my own Incredible 2. The phone does have a Micro-SD slot underneath the battery cover, and I guess we could put music on one of those and then stick it in the phone, but that'd be a hassle whenever he wants to put more music on, and I find it hard to believe that that entire 16 gigs is reserved for app space.

Comment: When you say you don't get the same prompt, I'm assuming you mean the pop-up window asking you what USB mode to use. Do you also lack a USB icon in the notification bar?

Comment: Are you sure the USB cable is not faulty. Also, do you see any other prompts when you connect it such as a notification on the phone that Debugging is On, or a notification on the PC that says the Driver Installation Failed?